# Prevent a component from being added to a jpanel if another component is already in place

Tags: java, swing, game-development

So I am in the process of creating a game similar to Plants vs Zombies, however I've run into a slight problem: before I can apply the finishing touches such as levels, I need to prevent more than one JLabel being added to a JPanel. The placing of the JLabel works fine, though I think that I may have gone a roundabout route. The problem as stated above is that another JLabel can currently be added below a pre-existing JLabel. How do I set a JPanel to accept no more than the original component (the initial JLabel)? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
private final JFrame FRAME;
private final JPanel squares[][] = new JPanel[8][11];
private final Color DGY = Color.DARK_GRAY;
private final Color GRN = Color.GREEN;
private final Color BLK = Color.BLACK;
private final Color LGY = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
private final Color GRY = Color.GRAY;
private final Color BLU = Color.BLUE;
private final Font F1 = new Font("Tahoma", 1, 36);
private String icon = "";
private int lvl = 10;

private void squareGen(int i, int j, Color col, boolean border)
{
    squares[i][j].setBackground(col);
    if (border)
    {
        squares[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(BLK, 1));
    }
    FRAME.add(squares[i][j]);
}

public GameGUI()
{
    FRAME = new JFrame("ESKOM VS SA");
    FRAME.setSize(1600, 900);
    FRAME.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 11));
    for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
    {
        if (x > 1 && x < 7)
        {
            squares[x][0] = new JPanel();
            squareGen(x, 0, GRN, true);
        } else if (x == 1 || x == 7)
        {
            squares[x][0] = new JPanel();
            squareGen(x, 0, DGY, true);
        } else
        {
            squares[x][0] = new JPanel();
            squareGen(x, 0, BLU, false);
        }
        for (int y = 1; y < 11; y++)
        {
            squares[x][y] = new JPanel();
            if (x == 0)
            {
                squareGen(x, y, BLU, false);
            } else if (y == 10 || x == 1 || x == 7)
            {
                squareGen(x, y, DGY, true);
            } else
            {
                squareGen(x, y, LGY, true);
                addDToPanel(x, y);
            }
        }
    }
    JButton btnPause = new JButton();
    btnPause.setText("||");
    btnPause.setFont(F1);
    btnPause.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
        {
            btnPauseActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    squares[7][10].add(btnPause);
    addButtons(8);
    FRAME.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    FRAME.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

public void restart()
{
    FRAME.dispose();
    GameGUI ggui = new GameGUI();
    ggui.setVisible(true);
}

public void mainMenu()
{
    FRAME.dispose();
    new StartUpUI().setVisible(true);
}

private void btnPauseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
    new PauseGUI(this).setVisible(true);
}

private void btnAddDefenseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
    JButton btn = (JButton) evt.getSource();
    icon = btn.getActionCommand();
}

private void addButtons(int x)
{
    JButton[] btn = new JButton[x];
    for (int j = 1; j <= x; j++)
    {
        btn[j - 1] = new JButton();
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("" + j + ".png"));
        btn[j - 1].setIcon(ii);
        btn[j - 1].setActionCommand("" + j);
        btn[j - 1].setText("");
        btn[j - 1].setForeground(btn[j - 1].getBackground());
        squares[0][j].add(btn[j - 1]);
        btn[j - 1].addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
            {
                btnAddDefenseActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
    }
}

private void addDToPanel(int x, int y)
{
    squares[x][y].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me)
        {
            JPanel panel = (JPanel) me.getSource();

            int j = (int) (panel.getX() / 145.45454545) + 1;
            int i = (int) (panel.getY() / 112.5) + 1;
            addDefense(i, j, icon);
            icon = "";
            FRAME.revalidate();
            FRAME.repaint();
        }
    });
}

private void addDefense(int i, int j, String imageName)
{
    try
    {
        JLabel jlbl = new JLabel();
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(imageName + ".png"));
        jlbl.setIcon(ii);
        squares[i][j].add(jlbl, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}

public void setLvl(int lvl)
{
    this.lvl = lvl;
}

public void setVisible(boolean b)
{
    FRAME.setVisible(b);
}
```

This is not my main class, this class is instantiated in the main class and setVisible() = true;
Again thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I set a JPanel to accept no more than the original

You can use the `Container.getComponentCount()` method to check how many components have been added to the panel.

Only add your component when the count is 0.

Comment: That returns the total number of components i.e. 88 JPanels. Is there a means of getting a container of a JPanel as opposed to FRAME.getContentPane()?

Comment: What are you talking about. Why are you using the content pane? Somewhere you have a `panel.add( someComponent )` statement. Well that is the panel you check to see is it has a component added to it. For example your MouseEvent code gets the panel using the `getSource()` method. I would think that is the panel you are concerned with but you know the logic better than me.